# Conditionally construct default-constructible classes of a parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a template class `Container` with a template constructor defined as follows:

```
template<class... Objects>
class Container
{
public:
    template<class... Objs>
    Container(Objs*... objs)
    {
        // initialize all pointers of m_objs to nullptr
        objs_init<Objects...>();

        // initialize the pointers of m_objs corresponding to parameters pack objs...
        objs_init<Objs...>(objs...);
    }

private:
    template<class Obj, class O1, class ...On>
    void objs_init()
    {
        objs_init<Obj>();
        objs_init<O1, On...>();
    }
    template<class Obj, class O1, class ...On>
    void objs_init(Obj* obj, O1* o1, On*... on)
    {
        objs_init<Obj>(obj);
        objs_init<O1, On...>(o1, on...);
    }
    template<class Obj>
    void objs_init(Obj* obj = nullptr)
    {
        std::get<Obj*>(m_objs) = obj;
    }

    std::tuple<Objects*...>     m_objs;
};
```

and some classes `A`, `B`, `C`, ... defined as follows:

```
class A { public: A(bool) {} };
class B { /*trivial default ctor*/ };
class C { public: C(int) {} };
```

If I create a `Container<A,B,C>` object this way:

```
    Container<A,B,C> cnt(new A(true), new C(1));
```

assuming all classes specified in template parameters are different, the `Container<>` template constructor works as expected, i.e.:

- all pointers of the `m_objs` tuple are first set to `nullptr`, then
- the 1st (`A*`) and 3rd (`C*`) pointers of `m_objs` are set to the values returned by `new A(true)` and `new C(1)` respectively.

Now, I would like the `Container<>` constructor to default-construct every uninitialized pointers of `m_objs`. But I don't know how to achieve this.

I tried adding the following template member functions to `Container<>`:

```
    template<class Obj, class O1, class ...On>
    void objs_ctor()
    {
        objs_ctor<Obj>();
        objs_ctor<O1, On...>();
    }
    template<class Obj>
    void objs_ctor()
    {
        Obj*& obj = std::get<Obj*>(m_objs);
        if (obj == nullptr)
            obj = new Obj;
    }
```

and a call to `objs_ctor<>` in `Container<>` constructor:

```
        // default-construct unitialized pointers of `m_objs`
        objs_ctor<Objects...>();
```

however, this obviously does not work because the way I implemented `objs_ctor<>` requires that a default constructor exists for every classes of the parameter pack (which I don't want to); so I get the following compiler error:

```
error C2512: 'A' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

In order for this to work,I also need to check if the object I try to automatically create is default-constructible. I think this could be achieved using `std::is_default_constructible<>` but I don't know how to use it properly.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis.

Add a call to `objs_ctors<Objects...>();` in constructor

```
  template<class... Objs>
     Container(Objs*... objs)
      {
        objs_init<Objects...>();
        objs_init<Objs...>(objs...);
        objs_ctors<Objects...>();
      }
```

and define `objs_ctor<>()` and `objs_ctors<>()` in this way

```
  template <typename Obj>
     typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_default_constructible<Obj>::value, void>::type objs_ctor ()
      {
        Obj * & obj = std::get<Obj*>(m_objs);

        if ( obj == nullptr)
           obj = new Obj;
      }

  template <typename Obj>
     typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_default_constructible<Obj>::value, void>::type objs_ctor ()
      { }

  template <typename Obj, typename O1, typename ... On>
     void objs_ctors()
      {
        objs_ctor<Obj>();
        objs_ctors<O1, On...>();
      }

  template <typename Obj>
     void objs_ctors ()
      {
        objs_ctor<Obj>();
      }
```

Attention, please: I suppose your example

```
    Obj*& obj = std::get<Obj*>(m_objs);
    if (obj != nullptr)
        obj = new Obj;
```

was wrong.

I suppose your intention was modify (allocate) `obj` when `obj` is a `nullptr`, so

```
    Obj*& obj = std::get<Obj*>(m_objs);
    if (obj == nullptr)
        obj = new Obj;
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.